# MS Access replace function is not giving the expected result

Tags: vba, microsoft-access, replacement

I am concatenating two fields, however in some cases the second field begins with `\`, but not always.

I'm trying to remove the possible extraneous `\` using replace.

```
stDigitalFolderLocation = stDigitalLocation & "\" & stDigitalFolder
stDigitalFolderLocation = replace(stDigitalFolderLocation, "\\ ", "\")
```

Answer (score 2):

Apologies, looking with fresh eyes I noticed an extra space.

```
stDigitalFolderLocation = replace(stDigitalFolderLocation, "\\ ", "\")
```

should be:

```
stDigitalFolderLocation = replace(stDigitalFolderLocation, "\\", "\")
```